# convert a word doc to text doc using C#

Tags: c#, regex, text, ms-word, converters

So I am currently trying to convert a word doc (.doc) into a text document because I want to use regular expressions on it to find things in the document.  So I came up with the below and it converts the word document into a rich text format (by appending it to a rich text box), but this does not translate into a plain text format.  When I tried with regular text document it printed every word on a new line.  I have not been able to find any information on how to do this in C#.  I'm using C# and visual studio 2010.

I do not expect any special characters in the document (like bold, underlines, etc.), but if someone knows how I can be robust and extract those that would be super awesome.

I want it as a text document because there's several methods I know I can use on regular text, but I doubt they would work on word text due to hidden/special characters that come with word docs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ReadWordDocProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string testFile = @"C:\Users\<mycomputer>\Documents\TestItemHelpers\TestWordDoc.docx";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Document document = application.Documents.Open(testFile);//path here

            int count = document.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                string text = document.Words[i].Text;
                //Do output with text here
                richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
            }

            ((_Application)application).Quit(); //cast as _Application because there's ambiguity 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: "When I tried with regular text document it printed every word on its a new line" What was the code you tried here?

Comment: As a non-programming solution, have you tried copying the entire document contents from within Word and pasting them into a text editor?  If this is just a one-off task, that's surely the quickest route to a text-only document.

Comment: I'll have a lot of files like this coming in and it seems a little impratical to do it by hand.  I know how to do it by hand, but I was hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: @BenAaronson I did a write line by line to a text doc just to test and see if it would work.  Do you think some special characters in word doc could have translated a text equivalent line to a word doc's single word?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) says you shouldn't use Microsoft Office Interop to manipulate documents in an automated application.

You can use a free library like [Spire Doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html#.U3UW3_mzFMw) to convert a Word Doc to TXT, then open the txt file. I think there is a way to save directly to `MemoryStream` from Spire, but I'm not sure. (I know there is in Aspose Words, but that isn't free).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open word document
    Document document = new Document();
    string docPath = @"C:\Users\<computer name>\Documents\TestItemHelpers";

    document.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(docPath,"TestWordDoc.docx"));

    //Save doc file.
    document.SaveToFile(Path.Combine(docPath,"TestTxt.txt"), FileFormat.Txt);

    string readText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(docPath,"TestTxt.txt"));

    //do regex here
}
```

Edit: If you're going to use Interop because it is okay for user-run activities (as pointed out in comments), you can save the document as a text file then do the regex:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string docPath = @"C:\Users\<computer name>\Documents\TestItemHelpers"
    string testFile = "TestWordDoc.docx";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(docPath,testFile );
    application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(Path.Combine(docPath,"TestTxt.txt"), WdSaveFormat.wdFormatText, ref noEncodingDialog);
    ((_Application)application).Quit();

    string readText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(docPath,"TestTxt.txt"));

    //do regex here
}
```

Comment: Your first link only applies to *server-side* processing. It is perfectly fine for user-run applications.

Comment: My program may get used for server side work so this might actually be perfect for me.

Comment: I added the Interop SaveAs just in case you were interested in looking at that way too.

Comment: So i looked at the spire doc stuff, but the free version will only read up to 100 paragraphs, and that probably won't work for my purposes.

Comment: There are other paid libraries that will read more than 100 paragraphs, but you can use this for testing. If you are going to use this on a server then you will definitely want to use something other than MS Word Interop.

Comment: If you're just going to be working with docx, another way to manipulate the document is OpenXML.

Comment: Spire hasn't been updated in a while, is there anything more current?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Interop or paid libraries like `Spire`, you can use [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi). It's a matured open source project to work with Word and Excel files.

Please note that Word file can have a complex structure like nesting tables or joined/splitted cells. That's why, I think, NPOI doesn't have an explicit `SaveAsText()` method. But if you need only text from paragraphs or tables, you can easily extract it like this (.NET 6 example):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> WordFileToText(string wordFilePath)
{
    using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(wordFilePath);
    using var doc = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    var result = WordFileToText(doc);
    return result;
}

private static IEnumerable<string> WordFileToText(XWPFDocument doc)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var bodyElement in doc.BodyElements)
    {
        if (bodyElement is XWPFParagraph paragraph)
        {
            result.Add(paragraph.Text);
            continue;
        }
        if (bodyElement is not XWPFTable table)
            continue;

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var tableLine = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var cell in row.GetTableCells())
            {
                foreach (var cellParagraph in cell.Paragraphs)
                {
                    tableLine.Append(cellParagraph.Text);
                    tableLine.Append("| ");
                }
            }
            result.Add(tableLine.ToString());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```