# Extract data from Word documents with SSIS to ETL into SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ms-word, etl, openxml

I could really use some help in how to extract data from Word documents using SSIS and inserting the extracted data in SQL. There are 10,000 - 13,000 Word files to process. The files most likely aren't consistent over the years. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is the example data from the Word documents that I'm interested in capturing. Note that `Date` and `Job No` are in the Header section.

**Customer**    :   Test Customer
**Customer Ref.**   :   123456
Contact :   Test Contact

**Part No.**    :   123456789ABCDEFG
**Manufacturer**    :   Some Mfg.
**Package** :   123-456
**Date Codes**  :   1234
**Lot Number**  :   123456
**Country of Origin**   :   Country
**Total Incoming Qty**  :   1 pc
**XRF Test Result** :   PASS
**HCT Result**  :   PASS
**Solder Test Result**  :   PASS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be this:

1. Create a [script in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ms-word-documents-using-python-ed3fbb48c122) that extracts your data from the Word files and save them in XML or JSON format
2. Create SSIS package to load the data from each XML/JSON file to SQL Server

Comment: Manntovani I was thinking of using a language to save the Word files in XML, Excel, etc. I'm not familiar with Python though. Do you know of any examples with C# or VB.NET? Thank you for your approach and comment!

Comment: There are many examples, Google them: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/How-to-Use-C-/VB.NET-to-Convert-Word-Doc-to-XML.html

Comment: @Franceso Mantovani Appreciate the example!

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Using a script component as a source

To import data from Microsoft Word into SQL Server, you can use a script component as a data source where you can implement a C# script to parse document files using Office Interoperability libraries or any third-party assembly.

- [Example of reading tables from a Word file](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/blob/master/SchemaMapperDLL/Classes/Converters/MsWordImport.cs)

#### 2. Extracting XML from DOCX file

DOCX file is composed of several embedded files. Text is mainly stored within an XML file. You can use a script task or Execute Process Task to extract the DOCX file content and use an XML source to read the data.

- [How can I extract the data from a corrupted .docx file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388444/how-can-i-extract-the-data-from-a-corrupted-docx-file)
- [How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files)

#### 3. Converting the Word document into a text file

The third approach is to convert the Word document into a text file and use a flat-file connection manager to read the data.

- [convert a word doc to text doc using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687066/convert-a-word-doc-to-text-doc-using-c-sharp)
- [Converting a Microsoft Word document to a text file in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/706253/Converting-a-Microsoft-Word-document-to-a-text-fil)

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what I was thinking in my head. The examples are very helpful. Thank you!